# How to align each paragraph specifically by Word Interop?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, alignment, office-interop

This is my code:

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oTable As Word.Table
Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph, oPara2 As Word.Paragraph
Dim oPara3 As Word.Paragraph, oPara4 As Word.Paragraph
Dim oRng As Word.Range

oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
oPara1.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(sNewData.Picture)
oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

oPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
oPara2.Range.Text = nTP.Nama
oPara2.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter

oPara2.Range.Font.Bold = True
oPara2.Range.Font.Size = 18
oPara2.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue
oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 6
oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
oPara3.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
oPara3.Range.Text = "Special arrangement for Mr/Mrs. " & customer
oPara3.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorOliveGreen
oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 3
oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

The strange thing is the **`oPara1`** is aligned at *left*, while **`oPara2`** is aligned at *center*. But the **`oPara3`** is not aligned at *left*.
The output is that **`oPara3`** is following the previous alignment which is *center*.
So how could I apply for a specific paragraph its own alignment or style?
I found some discussion about "`Style`" but I confused.

Answer (score 4):

This C# code aligns the whole Word document successfully:

```
foreach (Paragraph p in oWord.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
{
    p.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
}
```

Comment: @gumuruh, Do you need more help?

Comment: IMO, you answer was based on title of question, but in the body of question OP mentioned that needs to separate alignments of each paragraph ;).

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal was right, BUT:
    When you you modify the property TEXT in the code, the Alignment property restart to Left. 
You can try this inserting several times this code to "debug" the status of the Alignment property. One before you set the alignment, one after you modify the alignment, one after you change the "Text" property, then run the program.

```
Msgbox(oPara3.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment)
```

So the solution is to modify the Alignment just before inserting the Paragraph:

```
oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
/*oPara3.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft*/
oPara3.Range.Text = "Special arrangement for Mr/Mrs. " & customer
oPara3.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorOliveGreen
oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 3
oPara3.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

Comment: is that true?
i haven't tried yet. But... seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Adding a new paragraph is like pressing <kbd>Enter / Return</kbd>, so at first format of a new paragraph sets based on *Normal Style* then after changing any property of current paragraph, it stored as current format that will apply to new paragraphs from now on.
So to change this behavior that makes all new paragraphs to use same format instead of some situation I can suggest to use a method like this - but in C# -:

```
public static void AddParagraph(ref Document doc, string text, 
    WdParagraphAlignment align = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft, ...)
    // ... means for other format specifications you can do it same
{
    var para = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
    para.Alignment = align;
    para.Range.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
Range content = doc.Content;
Paragraph pText = content.Paragraphs.Add();                    
Text.Range.Text = "sadfsadfsda"
pText.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but the solutions mentioned here didn't help me.
So i'll post the solution here for ppl like me in hope it will help them.

The thing you need to do is set the Alignment property AFTER setting the Text property (see the code below).

```
'p1 is going to be right aligned
var p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
p1.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
p1.Range.Font.Size = 18
p1.Range.Text = "right"
p1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
p1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

'p2 is going to be center aligned
var p2 = document.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
p2.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
p2.Range.Font.Size = 16
p2.Range.Text = "center"
p2.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
p2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

'p3 is going to be left aligned
var p3 = document.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
p3.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
p3.Range.Font.Size = 14;
p3.Range.Text = "left"
p3.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
p3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

This is the way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me!

```
  Range content = doc.ActiveDocument.Content;

  Paragraph pText = content.Paragraphs.Add(); 

  pText.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
  WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

  doc.Selection.TypeText("some text");
```

Comment: Instead of writing "this worked for me", please edit your answer and explain why this piece of code answers the question.

Comment: This whole thread reflects a poor use of Word by all concerned. Paragraph formats should be managed via the use of Styles. If you first create the required Styles with all the relevant font & alignment attributes applied in whatever template the document is to be based on, all you need do is apply the relevant Style (e.g. doc.Paragraphs(3).Style = "stylename"). If you're working with a existing document, you can even create the Styles on the fly.